# Update JS object at arbitrary depth

Tags: javascript

I know that I can update an arbitrary field on an object quite simply.

```
var simpleObj = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: true,
    ky3: 47
};

function updateSimpleObj(key, value){
    simpleObj[key] = value;
}
```

But what if I have a much more complex object?

```
var funObj = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: simpleObj,
    key3: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
    key4: [{name: 'Alice', hired: true}, {name: 'Bob', hired: false}]
    key5: {
        name: table1, 
        values:[
                [0,1,2], 
                [{name: 'Alice', hired: true}, {name: 'Bob', hired: false}, {name: "Charles"}], 
                [true, false]
            ]
        }
};
```

How could I arbitrarily access any one of the nested values in `funObj`? Is there some kind of 'deep key' I can use?
I'm sure that if I get creative enough with LoDash I can probably loop my way through the object finding the keys that I need, but is there a simpler way?

Comment: Just use the dot and bracket notation: `funObj.key5.values[1][0].name`

Comment: i believe this question addressed this same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013011/find-by-key-and-replace-by-value-in-nested-json-object

Comment: Try using `object-path`, `immutable` or `immutability-helper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the lodash [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#merge) function.
First I had to reconstruct my `funObj` so it doesn't use arrays, only objects.
For every case of a possible update I need to carefully construct the hierarchy of the object, with just the value that I want. So something like this:

```
_.merge(funObj, {
    key5: {
        values: {
            1: {
                hired: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will result in:

```
var funObj = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: simpleObj,
    key3: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
    key4: [{name: 'Alice', hired: true}, {name: 'Bob', hired: false}]
    key5: {
        name: table1, 
        values:[
                [0,1,2], 
                [{name: 'Alice', hired: true}, {name: 'Bob', hired: true}, {name: "Charles"}], 
                [true, false]
            ]
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As trincot said, just use dot and bracket notation.

```html
<script>
var simpleObj = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: true,
    ky3: 47
};
var funObj = {
    key: {
        name: "table1", 
        values:[
                [0,1,2], 
                [{name: 'Alice', hired: true}, {name: 'Bob', hired: false}, {name: "Charles"}], 
                [true, false]
            ]
        }
};
 var bigObj = {
 key1: "string",
 key2: {
value: {val: 0}
 }
};
console.log("BigObj: "+bigObj.key2.value.val);
console.log("FunObj: "+funObj.key.values[1][0].name);
</script>
```

Comment: I want the function to be able to accept any one of multiple keys, to be determined at runtime.